# How do I parse a string in Django templates?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to have my django app display some text on the page.

My string, coming in from the view, would be something along the lines of:

`'Hello! This is my twitter @profile! send me an email at me@mail.com`

Now I want to be able to display the string as:

`'Hello! This is my twitter @profile! send me an email at me@mail.com`

BUT `@profile` (without the '!') must be a link to https://twitter.com/profile

If I make my logic in views and send as a string:

`Hello! This is my <a href="https://twitter.com/profile" target="_blank"> send me an eamil at me@mail.com`

The result will be to actually to see the tags, which I obviously don't.

How do I fix this? considering that the strings coming in will be many and I display them via a python-enabled loop.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is the way I am testing it (obviously I would need a good old regex I know)

Views.py

```py
def test1(response):
    text = "@RayFranco is answering to @AnPel, this is a real '@username83' but this is an@email.com."    
    sentenceList = text.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(sentenceList)):
        word = sentenceList[i]
        if word[0] == '@':
            sentenceList[i] = f'<a href="https://twitter.com/{sentenceList[i]}" target="_blank">{sentenceList[i]}</a>'
    
    return render(response, "main/test1.html", {'sentenceList':sentenceList})
```

test1.html

```
    <p>
        {% for word in sentenceList %}
            {{word}}
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
```

output:
[image]

Comment: so if "your string comes in from your view" you assigned it to a variable within the context of the http object. In the template you simply access it using the variable name like so `{{ your_variable }}`

Answer (score 1):

try to add the safe template tag on the template

```
{{ sentenceList|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/)

**Variables**

A variable outputs a value from the context, which is a dict-like object mapping keys to values.

Variables are surrounded by **{{** and **}}** like this:

```
My first name is {{ first_name }}. My last name is {{ last_name }}.
```

---

According to the [other part of docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render)

**A shortcut: `render()`**

It’s a very common idiom to load a template, fill a context and return an **HttpResponse** object with the result of the rendered template. Django provides a shortcut. Here’s the full **index()** view, rewritten:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: I added an edit to the question to make what I do clearer :-)